# Specializing a global template function inside another namespace

Tags: c++, templates

How can I specialize GetData function while still being inside a namespace?

```
#include <iostream>

class Person
{
public:
    Person() {}
};

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal() {}
};

template<typename T>
T GetData(const std::string& data)
{
    static_assert(false, "no specialization");
    return T{};
}

template<>
Person GetData<Person>(const std::string& data)
{
    return Person();
}

namespace ns
{
    template<>
    Animal GetData<Animal>(const std::string& data)
    {
        return Animal();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Person p = GetData<Person>(std::string(""));
    Animal a = GetData<Animal>(std::string(""));
    std::cout << "Program Completed\n";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error:

> error C2912 : explicit specialization 'Animal ns::GetData(const std::string &)' is not a specialization of a function template

Comment: Why do you want to specialize the template inside a namespace, when the template isn't part of the namespace? From what I know, that's simply not how it's done. What are you trying to gain from specializing that inside the namespace?

Comment: inside the namespace there are macros which generates these templates function. these macros can be called from any namespace even nested namespace. GetData function has to be global and should be invoked based on type.

Comment: macros are not "controlled by namespaces"... You can use this macro in every place...

Comment: Let me repeat the question for the macros, then. Why are your macros (invoked) inside a namespace if they are supposed to create toplevel functions (they will have to, otherwise you're defining `ns::GetData`)? Or are they creating the namespace with the specialization inside? (If they are, don't. Create include guards for the specializations instead.)

Comment: @PiotrNycz when macro get substituted by actual code its changing the namespace of that code. means if macro used in n namespaces, n version of function differ by namespace will be there.

Comment: @TinyT i cannot enforce client of my library to use macro in global namespace only that's why macros are in namespace. there might be better way to achieve this.

Comment: So you want a macro to generate code for a type your client will use. Among those, there is a function template needing a new specialization for that type. The function is toplevel. Does it have to be (because it extends another function that is toplevel as well)? If it's not too prominent to the user, I'd suggest creating the template inside a namespace and explicitly giving that namespace inside the macro. Still error-prone but hopefully a bit less sensitive.